# Can't get PHP's system function to call ghostscript or any other programs in PASE environment

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

I am trying to get PHP to convert PDFs to JPGs. I have installed GhostScript and can now do what I want from QP2TERM like this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=page%03d.jpg -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r288 test.pdf
```

However when I am in PHP, I try to use this and it does not work:

```
system("gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=page%03d.jpg -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r288 test.pdf");
```

For simplicity I also tried these but didn't get any output:

```
print system("convert --help");
print system("/bin/convert --help");
```

Also this does output TEST:

```
system('echo TEST');
```

but this does not output the path variable:

```
system('echo $PATH');
```

How can I go about getting this working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using [`passthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of `system` to aid in debugging?  From what I'm reading `system` only returns the last line of output.

Comment: I have tried that with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling the command like this:

```
i5_command("QSH CMD('gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=page%03d.jpg -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r288 test.pdf')", $connection);
```

It probably isn't the most optimal option but it works.